# How can implement this sql query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

[image]

I'm beginner of codeigniter .So can you any one help to implement this code to codeigniter,

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this code :**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('kotahena_customers');
$where = "date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and now()";
$this->db->where($where);
$results = $this->db->get()->result();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 1):

I give you a simple query here.

```
$this->db->where('date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND now()');
$data = $this->db->get('kotahena_customers')->result();
```

hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("kotahena_customers");
$this->db->where("date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW()", NULL, FALSE);
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it will help you.

function test()
{

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('kotahena_customers');
    $this->db->where('date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND now()');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```